# Symfony 2: Doctrine can't create relationship

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm very new to Symfony 2.0 and doctrine. I have state and customer entity in different bundle. I just want to add relation between state and customer. I'm coded state and customer entities. Here is the my code:

```
/**
 * @orm:Entity
 */
class Customer
{
    /**
     * @orm:Id
     * @orm:Column(type="integer")
     * @orm:GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="State")
     * @JoinColumn(name="state_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $state;

}

/**
 * @orm:Entity
 */
class State
{
    /**
     * @orm:Id
     * @orm:Column(type="integer")
     * @orm:GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @orm:Column(type="string", length="50")
     */
    protected $name;
}
```

And my config file:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        mappings:
            FogCustomerBundle: { type: annotation, dir: Entity/ }
            FogMainBundle: { type: annotation, dir: Entity/ }
```

So my problem is when I generate schema using `php app/console doctrine:schema:create` command tables are generated. But relationship doesn't generated /state column doesn't generead in customer table/. Why? I don't have any idea? I'll very happy for every advise and post.

Answer (score 9):

You can run into that problem if you're closely following examples from the Doctrine2 documentation, because Symfony2 places all the Doctrine2 annotations into the `orm` namespace, which you seem to be missing on your OneToOne and JoinColumn annotations. Your code for the $state property should look like this:

```
/**
 * @orm:OneToOne(targetEntity="State")
 * @orm:JoinColumn(name="state_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $state;
```

**EDIT:** With changes introduced in Symfony2 beta2, annotations have changed a little. Annotations need to be imported before they are used; importing Doctrine looks like this:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
```

Then the new usage looks like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="State")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="state_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $state;
```

There is [some discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/symfony-devs/VRgxOyf0_-w/discussion) of further changes to the annotation system; if these changes are rolled out, I'll be back with another edit.

Comment: Thank you for reply. According to your instruction I'm changed all '@orm' annotations to 'orm'. Then run 'code'php app/console doctrine:schema:create'code' command and get 'code'No Metadata Classes to process.'code' message. Tables are don't generated. Any idea?

Comment: Can you update your question with your new entities (ie replace the existing example with what they look like now)?